# Word boundaries to match strings containing dots (.) at begin/end

Tags: python, regex, word-boundary

I have a regex to match a **word** in a long **text**, like this:

```py
word = "word"
text = "word subword word"

def char_regex_ascii(word):
    return r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(word))

r = re.compile(my_regex(word), flags= re.X | re.UNICODE)
for m in r.finditer(text):
    print(m)
```

output:

```
word
word
```

The reason of `\b` is that I don't want to find substrings, but **full words**: for example I'm not interested in match the word `word` in the text `subword`, but I want only full words as results, so followed or anticipated by spaces, commas, dots or any kind of punctuation.

It works with the majority of the cases but if I insert a dot a the end of the word like `w.o.r.d.` it doesn't match because the last `\b` of the regex is after a dot.

```py
word = "w.o.r.d."
text = "w.o.r.d. subword word"

def char_regex_ascii(word):
    return r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(word))

r = re.compile(my_regex(word), flags= re.X | re.UNICODE)
for m in r.finditer(text):
    print(m)
```

output:

```
(nothing)
```

I see that using `\B` make it work, but I should do several checks at the begin and end of the sentences trying all the combinations of `\b` and `\B` for many words to find.

```py
word = "w.o.r.d."
text = "w.o.r.d. subword word"

def char_regex_ascii(word):
    return r"\b{}\B".format(re.escape(word))

r = re.compile(my_regex(word), flags= re.X | re.UNICODE)
for m in r.finditer(text):
    print(m)
```

output:

```
w.o.r.d.
```

Does a general approach exist?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex pattern `\w+(?:\.?\w+)*`, along with `re.findall`:

```py
text = "w.o.r.d. subword word"
matches = re.findall(r'\w+(?:\.?\w+)*', text)
print(matches)  # ['w.o.r.d', 'subword', 'word']
```

The pattern used here defines a "word" as being:

```regex
\w+         one or more word characters
(?:
    \.?\w+  followed by optional dot and one or more
            word characters
)*          zero or more times
```

Under this definition, acronym style terms such as `w.o.r.d.` would be captured as matches.